# Automapper mapping EF projectable properties first, then other properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, automapper, projection

I have something like this:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<UserProfile, UserDTO>()
            .ForMember(t => t.UserImage, s => s.MapFrom(x => x.Picture(32)))
            .ForMember(t => t.Permalink, s => s.MapFrom(x => x.Permalink()));
```

And I try something like this:

```
   unit.UserProfiles.GetAll().Project().To<UserDTO>().First();
```

I get something like:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Picture(xx.xxx.UserProfile, Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I would like to tell automapper to project map every property other then those two and after query is done to map those two in normal way, is it doable?

Answer (score 2):

You're asking the wrong question here. You really need to ask "how can my underlying query provider defer some of the projection to after the queryable does its job". This would involve a two-step process that Entity Framework would need to support. Here's the code, without AutoMapper going on:

```
unit.UserProfiles.Select(profile => new UserDTO {
    Id = profile.Id, // I made these two up
    Name = profile.Name,
    UserImage = profile.Picture(32),
    Permalink = profile.Permalink()
}).First();
```

How would EF interpret this? Not well, I assume. Probably an exception. If you wanted to do this in EF, you'd need to do something like:

```
unit.UserProfiles.Select(profile => new UserDTO {
    Id = profile.Id, // I made these two up
    Name = profile.Name
    UserImage = profile.UserImage,
    Slug = profile.Slug
}).First();
```

And then include the logic of creating a picture as part of UserDTO.

Alternatively, you'd just get the User out, and map afterwards. The key here is that AutoMapper only creates a Select projection, and it's up to the underlying query provider to handle it appropriately. AutoMapper can't guess what is supported or not, nor can it know how to resolve your custom methods, which are on the *source type*, and what data is needed from SQL.

Ask first - how would I accomplish this with a Select projection in EF? Then AutoMapper will take care of encapsulating that projection.

Comment: Thanks for response, I know that EF will not able to interpret it and I'm not trying to make EF do it, I also know that automapper only creates projection. I was wondering if I could tell AM to create select projection for some of properties, and for others tell it not to project them, but to map them after query is finished and we have object. I could implement those methods on DTO and put call to them in getter, I was just curious, btw. great library.

Comment: Think about it though - how would AutoMapper know to tell EF which properties also need to come back? Remember the point of LINQ projection is to alter the *SQL* query. How do I know what to include in that original SQL query, then keep it around somehow (remember, the original source object NEVER gets hydrated by your ORM), invoke a method on the source object that doesn't exist, and then map it? You're describing a scenario in which LINQ projection is impossible.